# Next JS Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')

Tags: django, next.js

I am using the `Django rest framework` in the backend. When the user enters the wrong credential, I sent 400 status from the backend. In the frontend, I am using `NEXT.js`. In the signin `route.js` I am getting the following error when the status is not 200.

`- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:261:61) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)`

The code for `route.js` is:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request) {
  const body = await request.json();
  // console.log(body);

  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_api/login_user/",
      body,
      config
    );

    // console.log(response.status);
    const data = response.data;
    const { message } = data;
    const nextResponse = new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(data), {
      status: 200,
    });
    const { token } = data;
    nextResponse.cookies.set("token", token, { httpOnly: true, path: "/" });
    return nextResponse;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log("Here: ", error.response.data);
      // console.log(error.response.data);
      // return new NextResponse(error, { status: response.status });
    }
  }
}
```

In the python code I am sending the response in this way:

```
return Response({
        'error': str(e),
        'message': 'User does not exists, please register first'
    }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Can anyone help me to find out what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import axios from "axios";

import { NextResponse, NextCookies } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request) {
const body = await request.json();

 try {
const config = {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};

const response = await axios.post(
  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_api/login_user/",
  body,
  config
);

const data = response.data;
const { token } = data;

const nextResponse = new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(data), {
  status: 200,
});

NextCookies.set(request, "token", token, { httpOnly: true, path: "/" });

return nextResponse;
 } catch (error) {
console.error("Error during POST request:", error);

// Construct an appropriate error response and return it to the client
return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: "Something went wrong." }), {
  status: 500,
});
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).